# How to define "euler package" as default on textgreek?

Tags: accents, euler

I want to write "ένταση" in Euler font. But i don't know how to configure the textgreek parameters properly. I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}


\begin{document}


    \Huge\textgreek{έ}\Large\textgreek{νταση} % option1. cbgreek

    {\Huge\textepsilon}\textnu\texttau \textalpha \textsigma \texteta % option2. euler - but it does not appear accent



\end{document}
```

That print:
[image]

So, what i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euler fonts have been produced for *mathematics* and are not suitable for text. In particular they miss accents, but also proper kerning.

You can use Artemisia, instead. Note also that capital letters don't wear accents, which are instead placed besides and in front of them.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[artemisia]{textgreek}

\usepackage{eulervm} % for comparison

\begin{document}

\textgreek{Ένταση}

$E\nu\tau\alpha\sigma\eta$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer**

The problem is that the accented epsilon is not available in the euler font from textgreek. In the following example, a fall-back character from cmr is used.

For the remaining part of the word, you can get the euler font with `\textgreekfont`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}

\begin{document}

    \textgreekfont 
    \Huge έ\Large νταση

    {\Huge\textepsilon}\textnu\texttau \textalpha \textsigma \texteta % option2. euler - but it does not appear accent



\end{document}
```

[image]